# Adding a Component to an other from a third one

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a ReactJS app where I have a 3 components, `Sidebar`, `Dashboard` and `Widget`.

`Sidebar`, `Dashboard` are rendered inside the main App container

```
...
class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Sidebar/>
        <Dashboard/>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

React.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

`Sidebar` contains a list of items and when one of them is clicked I want to add (append) to the `Dashboard` a `Widget` component.

The `Dashboard` component is basically empty

```
...
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div id="dashboard" className="dashboard">
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

And `Sidebar` has the list of items

```
...
 addWidget (widget) {
    // What does I do here?
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className="sidebar">
        <nav className="nav">
          <ul>
            {this.state.items.map((item) => (
              <li key={item.id}><span onClick={ this.addWidget.bind(this, item.name) }>{item.name}</span></li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Which options do I have to append a `Widget` when an item is clicked?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When I run into this scenario I often follow the "data down, actions up" approach. (Which is kind of an Ember name for it, but I find that it matches up with Flux quite a bit.) What I would do is send an action from your Sidebar to your App and tell it to add another widget to the Dashboard. For instance, something like this might work.

In your sidebar, pass the widget clicked on into a callback that was passed in by the App component:

```
addWidget(widget) {
    this.props.onWidgetAdded(widget);
}
```

Then in your app component, add that widget to a list of widgets and pass it to the Dashboard component:

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            widgets: []
        };
    }

    onWidgetAdded(widget) {
        // Perform some logic to get a component, then add it to the list
        const component = ...

        this.setState({
            widgets: this.state.widgets.concat([component])
        });
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Sidebar onWidgetAdded={this.onWidgetAdded} />

                <Dashboard>
                    {this.state.widgets}
                </Dashboard>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

Now in your Dashboard component you can use `this.props.children` to get the list of widgets that you need to render.

You might want to tweak a few things, such as how to send the action to the App component, how the widgets are created, or how they're passed to the Dashboard component, but this should give you the idea.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I give it a try and see where I end up.

Comment: It works quite well. But now how do I tell from App to Sidebar to display again the li when the widget is removed. I went ahead and also hidden the li when the widget is on the dashboard. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you need to send that information back to the sidebar, you may not be structuring your app correctly. If both your sidebar and your dashboard need access to the widgets but they're siblings of each other, the widgets shouldn't be contained in one component or the other. The widgets should live at a higher level so they can then be accessed by both components. This could be the App component or it could be a Flux-ish store. Either way, you'll likely want to re-think the location where the widgets live. (Trying to do it your current way will likely result in circular dependency issues.)